# Meaning of "$\leftrightarrow$" in "Markov matrix [...] with $J(x,y)>0 \leftrightarrow J(y,x)>0$"

Tags: notation, markov-chains

In the paper (2009) by Persi Diaconis:
**The markov chain monte carlo revolution**. *Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society, 46(2), 179-205* available [HERE](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eshmuel/Network-course-readings/MCMCRev.pdf), the author uses the symbol $\leftrightarrow$ in chapter $2.2$ (Metropolis algorithm), writing:

> Markov matrix [...] with $J(x,y)>0 \leftrightarrow J(y,x)>0$

Can someone explain me what $\leftrightarrow$ is supposed to mean exactly in this context?

Comment: If and only if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "if and only if"; you might also see this written as $$J(x,y) > 0 \iff J(y,x) > 0.$$ In context, it means that we are looking at a Markov chain where no transition is a "purely one-way" transition: if it is possible to go from state $x$ to state $y$ in a single step, then it is possible to go from $y$ to $x$ in a single step as well.

Comment: Good, thanx. So, it has nothing to do with the fact that all $J(x,y)$ should be strictly positive, right?

Comment: No, it is not required for all $J(x,y)$ to be positive. If $J(x,y) = J(y,x) = 0$, then the acceptance ratio $A(x,y)$ technically has a division by zero in it, but in that case we should take $A(x,y)=0$ and $K(x,y)=0$ as well. In practice, $J$ and $K$ will often be fairly sparse. We *do* want $J$ to be irreducible (there is some, possibly very long, path from every $x$ to every $y$).

Comment: For example, in the example at the top of p. 5, $J(f,f^*)$ is $0$ for almost all pairs $(f,f^*)$: there is only a transition from $f$ to $f^*$ if we can turn $f$ into $f^*$ by switching two symbols. However, this condition is symmetric:  if we can turn $f$ into $f^*$ by switching two symbols, then we can turn $f^*$ into $f$ by switching them back. So the condition that $J(x,y) > 0 \iff J(y,x) > 0$ is satisfied.

Comment: Nice! The acceptance ratio was causing me a concern, but since we apply the rule to impose a null value in the event of $0/0$, everything becomes clear.